# importerror : cannot import name 'secure_write' while updating python in conda evironment

Tags: python-3.x

I want to update my python version to python 3.6 ,
 I am using conda environment therefore used the following command on the terminal :
`conda install python=3.6`

while installation I'm encountered with this error : `importerror : cannot import name 'secure_write'`
Any help???

Answer (score 29):

Upgrade the jupyter client

```
pip install --upgrade jupyter_client
```

This error was reported for jupyter client at https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5014

Comment: And the problem is the same!!

Answer (score 0):

First I did 
pip uninstall jupyter_client
then 
pip install jupyter_client 
this helped me fix the error

Answer (score 0):

This made is simple.

conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab

Answer (score 0):

If you are using different conda environments in jupyter, `jupyter_client` needs to be updated in the conda environment where this issue is occurring.

E.g.:

```bash
conda activate [conda environment name]
```

and then

```bash
pip install --upgrade jupyter_client
conda deactivate
```